# Как с помощью reduce сделать так, чтобы она считала и возвращала общее количество всех пользователей из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Пытаюсь разобраться `reduce()` помогите.

Дополни функцию `getTotalFriendCount(users)` так, чтобы она считала и возвращала общее количество друзей (свойство friends) всех пользователей из массива users.

```
const user = [
  {
    name: "Moore Hensley",
    email: "moorehensley@indexia.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 2811,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Sharlene Bush",
    email: "sharlenebush@tubesys.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Briana Decker", "Sharron Pace"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3821,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "Ross Vazquez",
    email: "rossvazquez@xinware.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Marilyn Mcintosh", "Padilla Garrison", "Naomi Buckner"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 3793,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Elma Head",
    email: "elmahead@omatom.com",
    eyeColor: "green",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Aisha Tran"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2278,
    gender: "female"
  },
  {
    name: "Carey Barr",
    email: "careybarr@nurali.com",
    eyeColor: "blue",
    friends: ["Jordan Sampson", "Eddie Strong"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 3951,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Blackburn Dotson",
    email: "blackburndotson@furnigeer.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Jacklyn Lucas", "Linda Chapman"],
    isActive: false,
    balance: 1498,
    gender: "male"
  },
  {
    name: "Sheree Anthony",
    email: "shereeanthony@kog.com",
    eyeColor: "brown",
    friends: ["Goldie Gentry", "Briana Decker"],
    isActive: true,
    balance: 2764,
    gender: "female"
  }
]

const getTotalFriendCount = users => {
   users.reduce(
    (total, user) => total + user.length ,0);
};
```

Comment: Один из условий задачи это использование метода reduce().
Для перебора параметра users используется метод reduce()

Answer (score 0):

```
const getTotalFriendCount = users => {
  return users.reduce(
    (total, userItem) => total + userItem.friends.length ,0);
};

console.log(getTotalFriendCount(user))
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо сам успел разобраться

```
const getTotalFriendCount = users => 
   users.reduce(
  (total, user) => (user.friends.length += total),
  0);
```

Comment: `+=` оператор изменяет исходные данные в массиве. Лучше просто `+` используйте.